# Grab the current commit of a project and display it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, git, git-commit

## Issue

I was working on a project where QAs report bugs that already fixed.
So many time, it turn out that QAs don’t have our latest code.

---

## Solution

Now, I’m thinking to grab the current commit and display it in the `console` or on other page for references between us QA, and Developers.

---

## Tried

In CLI,  to get the latest commit, I just to do this

```
git rev-parse --verify HEAD
```

I’ve tried create a PHP function, and call it.

```
public function info(){
    return str_replace('\n','', json_encode(shell_exec('git rev-parse --verify HEAD')));
}
```

---

## Result

It works fine on my Mac, but on my QA set up, they got `null`.

---

## Questions

What did I do wrong ?

Is there another way to do this ?

I’m open to any suggestions at the moment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git` expects to be called from Git working directory tree as presumably it was when you executed it from the command line. PHP scripts initially set the `PWD` parent working directory environment variable to the directory in which the script is located and that's the same for command execution (exec, shell_exec, system, passthru). You can change directory from within PHP using [chdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) or change the command to

```
cd /path/to/git/repo && git rev-parse --verify HEAD
```